# Multiple AJAX calls in .each(), do something once all are done even if multiple errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube

I'm trying to check on dead YouTube videos with HEAD requests to `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<videoID>`. 
Now the thing is these are quick and all, but they will fail with 403 and 404:

> `HEAD https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/XmQR4_hDtpY 404 (Not Found)`

and these errors seem to mess things up.

I found [Multiple ajax calls inside a each() function.. then do something once ALL of them are finished? - Stack Overflow](/questions/8726046/multiple-ajax-calls-inside-a-each-function-then-do-something-once-all-of-the) and tried to use [this answer](/a/8726116/1318227):

```js
var videoIDs = ['a9KvHnHQVTc', 'XmQR4_hDtpY', 'WelBUaf5qsw', 'Mcrt9LJkGT4', 'P9qTLa2DVR8'];
var calls = [];
var deadVids = [];

$.each(videoIDs, function(index, value) {
    calls.push($.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + value,
        error: function() {
            deadVids.push('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + value + " is dead!");
        }
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, calls).always(function(){
     console.log(deadVids.length);
   });
```

With `.then` it never logs `deadVids.length` (= **4**) at all, with `.always` or `.fail` it logs **1** after the first error.

How can I do something once all the requests have finished, even if with errors?

(Ultimately this code will run as a bookmarklet, on reddit.com `$.fn.jquery -> "2.1.1"`)

---

EDIT: This seems to explain why it only logs **1**:

- If **all** the deferreds are resolved, execute the `done` callbacks.
- If **one** of the deferreds is rejected, execute the `fail` callbacks.

via http://afgomez.es/blog/better-ajax-callbacks-with-jquery-promises/

EDIT 2: Using global Ajax event handler `.ajaxStop()` attached to `document` does log **4** at the end of all AJAX requests

```js
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log(deadVid);
});
```

**EDIT 3**: Using .always() has been suggested but it wouldn't work for me... it would trigger after the 1st error. I was on Chrome 38, but when I tried Firefox 33 it works as expected, logs after all AJAX requests are done (1 OK and 4 failed, logs 4). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You only specify a succes function on the last call.

try

```
$.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
        console.log(deadVid);
}, function(){
  //log failed
});
```

Comment: Surely the fail can happen halfway through the process? Use `always` instead of `then` as Andy suggests.

Comment: Indeed... always is the safer bet here!